# Alphabetize list from query with specific associated row selected in dropdown

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write an SQL query that would populate a dropdown box of locations. In addition, I need the query to select the location associated with a user automatically (ie: be the first in the list results.)  I had the following, but recently realized that the list isn't completely alphabetized. To add another level to this, presume that I only have SELECT access to this database.

```
select  
    [LOCATION] 
from User_Table
where [ALIAS] = 'UserName' 
UNION all 

select 
    distinct [LOCATION]
from Location_Table 
where [STATUS_VALUE] ='Open'
```

If I "order by 1", then the location associated with the user is shuffled in with others and not the first item on the list.

Any help would be awesome.

EDIT: Maybe this will help to make it clearer. The larger list of locations seem to be built quasi-alphabetically based on their indexes. So halfway through the list, I get results like this:

WOODBRIDGE
YOKOTA/JAPAN
ABERDEEN PROVING GROUND
ALBUQUERQUE

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [LOCATION]
FROM 
(
select  
    [LOCATION], 1 AS [Sort]
from User_Table
where [ALIAS] = 'UserName' 
UNION all 

select 
    distinct [LOCATION], 0 AS [Sort]
from Location_Table 
where [STATUS_VALUE] ='Open'
) Locations
ORDER BY [Sort]
```

Comment: Sort values are backwards for Users Location to appear first.

Comment: Interestingly, that produces the same results as my query, except the current location is at the bottom. Adding "desc", to it provides the exact same results. Thanks!